# Regex - string excluded both before and after main expression

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

Given three URLS:

- `http://stackoverflow.com/questionsss/3003310`  -> true
- `http://stackoverflow.com/questionsss/3003310?s=1` -> false (s=1 found)
- `http://stackoverflow.com/questionsss?s=1&N=3003310` -> false (s=1 found)

How can I write a Regex in JS that returns true if 3003310 is found in the URL and false if s=1 is found anywhere in the URL.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

maybe something [like this](https://regex101.com/r/fPpOfs/2):

```
^(?=.*3003310)(?!.*\bs=1\b).*
```

a positive lookahead, and a negative one, for each condition. the `\b` word boundaries around `s=1` prevent false positives such as `sass=1` or `s=100`.

Answer (score 0):

**REGEXP:**

```
(.*\?s=1.*)
```

u should do a method, if result is equal to regex match. it will return FALSE else TRUE.

**Original Text:**

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questionsss/3003310 -> true
http://stackoverflow.com/questionsss/3003310?s=1 -> false (s=1 found)
http://stackoverflow.com/questionsss?s=1&N=3003310 -> false (s=1 found)
```

**Result:**

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questionsss/3003310?s=1 -> false (s=1 found)
http://stackoverflow.com/questionsss?s=1&N=3003310 -> false (s=1 found)
```

**Algorithm:**

```
Print(!OriginalText.equals(MethodCheck(Result)) // if empty. it will be TRUE
```

See: https://regex101.com/r/335HNW/1

Comment: Thanks for your help. It's not what I want, though.